# If else won't accept class

Tags: php

Im trying to make my language switcher change font weight depending on the language url but i cannot get it to accept the class

```
if ($_REQUEST["lang"] == "en") 
{ 
    echo '<div class="langlight"><a href="http://xyz.com/">Svenska</a></div>';
} 
else 
{
    echo '<div class="langbold"><a href="http://xyz.com/">Svenska</a></div>';

};

if ($_REQUEST["lang"] == "en") 
{
    echo '<div class="langbold"><a href="http://xyz.com/">English</div>';
} 
else 
{
    echo '<div class="langlight"><a href="xyz.com/">English</div>';
};
```

Comment: is `|` a bad copy and paste after the first `else`?

Comment: What is the value of `$_REQUEST["lang"]`? (hint: Use `var_dump($_REQUEST);` )

Comment: What output are you getting? You should not have a trailing `;` after `}`:  `};`

Comment: @BookOfZeus - I assume it was a separator between two blocks of code as it was between two `<?php ` sets. I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolons, missing closing tags:

```
if ($_REQUEST["lang"] == "en") 
{ 
    echo '<div class="langlight"><a href="http://xyz.com/">Svenska</a></div>';
} 
else 
{
    echo '<div class="langbold"><a href="http://xyz.com/">Svenska</a></div>';

}

if ($_REQUEST["lang"] == "en") 
{
    echo '<div class="langbold"><a href="http://xyz.com/">English</a></div>';
} 
else 
{
    echo '<div class="langlight"><a href="xyz.com/">English</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: Still it wount acceps the class. How can I write this so it doesent redirect me to the home page each time. If im on a nother page it shoud link to the translation of the same page ?

Comment: There seems to be a conflict with the </a> and the class but I dont know why ?